# Excel formula to obtain a cell value by setting another cell values at the same time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've made a calculator to calculate 2 parameters (`Re` and `De`) by getting 3 inputs (`Channel No`, `Flow rate`, and `Flow direction`) and computing 5 intermediate variables (`Area`, `Perimeter`, etc.) using VLOOKUP.

[image]

Now, for making some graphs, I need to set the input values one-by-one to obtain the outputs (`Re` and `De`) within a wide range of valid inputs. However, doing this manually would take so long.

Is there any ***formula*** that assigns values to the input cells and returns the output value of the calculator?

***EDIT:***

That is not really a big deal to implement it in VBA. However, it could be a nice idea to do this using a function.

```
Sub btnPopulateData_Click()
Dim Ch As Integer
Dim FD As Integer

' FD: Flow direction
FD = 1

For Ch = 1 To 7
    Sheets("Calculator").Range("M3").Value = Ch

    For Q = 0.5 To 9 Step 0.5
        Sheets("Calculator").Range("M4").Value = Q
        Sheets("Forward Graphs").Cells(5 + Ch, 3 + Q / 0.5).Value = Sheets("Calculator").Range("M11").Value

        ...
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you should look at some vba code here - the code pastes into the input values, forces a re-calculate then copies and pastes values for the output to a separate area.

Comment: Well, VBA works for sure, but any formulas serving this purpose?

Comment: The only ones, but both are manual, are Goalseek and solver - sure both can be driven via vba. Or, make a list of input values and write your formulae so you can drag it down giving the result.